# How to run a function once while mapping over multiple values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I'm using intersection observer to check if an element is visible on the page and scrolling to it, if it is not then I'm scrolling to that component. I'm doing this using React and Reacts `createRef` but I have multiple elements and I want to scroll to the first non-visible one on click.

Here's what I've got so far

```
import Card from '../Card/Card'
import styles from './Campaigns.module.scss'
import { campaignData } from '../../mockdata/campaigndata'
import { createRef, useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import Button from '../Button/Button'

const Campaigns = () => {
  const refs = campaignData.map(() => createRef<HTMLDivElement>())
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState<number>(0)
  const checkIntersection = (ref: HTMLDivElement) => {
    const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
      if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
        ref.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth',
        })
      }
    })
    if (ref) intersectionObserver.observe(ref)
  }
  const handleScroll = (direction: 'left' | 'right') => {
    if (direction === 'left' && offset > 0 && refs) {
      refs.map(ref => {
        if (ref) checkIntersection(ref.current as HTMLDivElement)
        
      })
      setOffset(offset - 1)
    } else {
      if (offset <= refs.length - 1 && offset >= 0 && refs) {
        refs.map(ref => {
          if (ref) checkIntersection(ref.current as HTMLDivElement)
          
        })
        setOffset(offset + 1)
      }
    }
  }
  return (
    <section className={styles.campaigns}>
      <h3></h3>
      <div>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            handleScroll('left')
          }}
          // disabled={checkIntersection(0)}
        >
          left
        </Button>
        <br />
        <Button
          onClick={() => handleScroll('right')}
          // disabled={checkIntersection(refs[refs.length - 1])}
        >
          right
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className={styles['cards-container']}>
        {campaignData.map(({ image, title, description }, index) => (
          <Card
            image={image}
            title={title}
            info={description}
            key={index}
            forwardRef={refs[index]}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Campaigns
```

I've tried using `window` to make this run once every action, but since I'm using Typescript I can't modify `window` as it's illegal.

Any other ways of doing this without using an array to store what's visible and what is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't say this is an optimal solution. Following might work. What I did was I have taken entire width(100%) to display the divs(cards) and assuming each div width(20%). So in the parent div we can fit 5 divs(5 cards). As we are updating the offset whenever we click on left and right then based on offset by doing some calculation I am moving the scroll bar to the first non visible element. I have hard coded the values for now but I think we can get those from css variables.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-6u05e7?file=/src/IntersectionObserver/IntersectionObserver1.js

Comment: This looks really good! The only problem I see with this is that moving each `div`  20% may result in funky behaivor in mobile screens which is totaly fixable with js media queries other than that I see no problems. Thanks!